# SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;

Tags: android, xml

I've searched for all my xml files and add this line at first: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but still doing the same error

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; O
>   conteúdo não é permitido no prólogo.

Comment: I've searched for all my xml files and add this line at first:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> but still doing the same error

Comment: Delete the XML file and recreate it. It has some bad characters

Comment: i've tried this but still not working

Comment: How are you creating the file?

Comment: You have something in the XML file before the root element (maybe a comment?).

Comment: i've looked in all my xml files, but i didn't find nothing wrong.

Comment: my xml files are generated by android studio